# unable to return my variable in list in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
 else if (searchtype == "Remarks")
                {
                  searchdata = (from po in db.POModels
                                  from ac in db.AccountMasterModels.Where(c => c.AccountTypeID == 1)
                                  join pd in db.PODetailsModels on po.POID equals pd.POID
                                  where (pd.Remarks.Contains(Search) && (po.PODate >= FromDate && po.PODate <= ToDate)) && (po.FirmID == userinfo.FirmID)
                                  select new
                                      {

                                      PONumber =po.PONumber,
                                      PODate = po.PODate,
                                      CompanyName = ac.CompanyName,
                                      Remarks = po.Remarks,

                                   }
                                      ).ToList<POModels>();    ##here is the error ##

                    }
```

Unable to return this to the list

How do I do this in this case, please help!!

I also tried this

```
 else if (searchtype == "Remarks")
                {
                  searchdata = (from po in db.POModels
                                  from ac in db.AccountMasterModels.Where(c => c.AccountTypeID == 1)
                                  join pd in db.PODetailsModels on po.POID equals pd.POID
                                  where (pd.Remarks.Contains(Search) && (po.PODate >= FromDate && po.PODate <= ToDate)) && (po.FirmID == userinfo.FirmID)
                                  select po).ToList();
```

It doesn't work either

Comment: What is the declared type of `searchdata`?

Comment: The first one is definitely not going to work, because you are constructing a list of objects of an anonymous type and then claim that they are `POModels`. If all the fields are properties of `POModel` you could try replacing `select new { ... ` with `select new POModel() { ...`.

Comment: What's the error text?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `<POModels>` into your ToList method. just do ToList , and if you want a POModel list instead of define an anonymous type you should define a `POModel:`

```
select new  POModel {
                PONumber =po.PONumber,
                PODate = po.PODate,
                CompanyName = ac.CompanyName,
                Remarks = po.Remarks,

             }.ToList();
```

Or probably your `POModel` class doesn't contain `CompanyName` property so you should use anonymous type:

```
select new {
                PONumber =po.PONumber,
                PODate = po.PODate,
                CompanyName = ac.CompanyName,
                Remarks = po.Remarks,

             }.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too use an anonymous object or you define your own. Example

```
public class NewPPModel
{
    public int PONumber  { get; set; }
    public DateTime PODate   { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName   { get; set; }
    public string Remarks   { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
searchdata = (from po in db.POModels
          from ac in db.AccountMasterModels.Where(c => c.AccountTypeID == 1)
          join pd in db.PODetailsModels on po.POID equals pd.POID
          where (pd.Remarks.Contains(Search) && (po.PODate >= FromDate && po.PODate <= ToDate)) && (po.FirmID == userinfo.FirmID)
          select new NewPPModel
              {

              PONumber =po.PONumber,
              PODate = po.PODate,
              CompanyName = ac.CompanyName,
              Remarks = po.Remarks

           }
              ).ToList();
```

Comment: Obviously POModels is an IEnumerable or something like that,then how could this work? `select new POModels`

Comment: If it is a IEnumerable what does it contains ? Does it contain POModel? then you select new POModel instead of POModels.

Comment: Why is POModels an IEnumerable ? In documentation it says "The type of elements of source".

Comment: Yes it is a bit confusing. If it is only PoModel you want then you dont even need to "select new .." it will be enough with "select po"

Comment: it has to be a list or IQueryable probably.I think `new POModels {` won't even compile.Because you can't make a query on a single element.

Comment: @Tan, he is using select new because he is getting some information from other entities: `CompanyName = ac.CompanyName`

Comment: @Selman22 oh i missed that. Either way he has to use a anonymous object or create a new defined object for it.

Comment: @Tan, yes,we both said that but probably `select new POModel` won't work either :D I guess POModel class doesn't contain a CompanyName property.He should use anonymous type

Comment: @jibran Maybe we shuold ask you. What object do you want it to return ?